# Layout data based on store don't update on store update

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-store

Hey guys I have this page layout, where I want to store in a sidebar, updated data about my user credentials (from a API that I update and store in a SvelteKit Store).

The problem is, no matter what I do the data from the sidebar doesn't update, in the other hand at any other page it updates.

I tried several things like calling the store trough reactive variables, but nothing seems to work...

This is the code of my +layout.svelte, I can provide. any other file if needed...

I have this page called main: `src/routes/main/+page.svelte`

```
<script>

@ts-nocheck

import { tokens } from "../../lib/auth";export let data;console.log(data);

export let token = "";
$: if ($tokens) {
    token = $tokens.refresh_token
}

</script>

<p>{"Store data from main page: "+ data.tokens.refresh_token}</p><div class="container mx-auto p-8 space-y-8"><h1 class="h1">Main</h1>

<ol class="list">
    {#each data.items.data as item}
        <li>
            <span>{item.id}</span>
            <span class="flex-auto">{item.title}</span>
        </li>
    {/each}
</ol>

</div>
```

For this page I have a layout for it: `src/routes/main/+layout.svelte`

```
<script lang="ts">

import { get, writable, type Writable } from "svelte/store";

export let data;
$: currentToken = data

</script>

<p>{"Store data from the layout: " + currentToken.refresh_token}</p>

<slot/>
```

and a server file for this layout: `src/routes/main/+layout.server.ts`

```
import { tokens } from "$lib/auth";

// Subscribe to refreshToken
let refreshedTokens: {
    refresh_token: string;
    access_token: string;
  };
  tokens.subscribe((data) => {
    refreshedTokens = data;
  });

  // Executes before send to client side
export const load = async () => { 
    return refreshedTokens
}
```

this is my store file: `/src/lib/auth.js`

```
// src/lib/auth.js
import { writable } from "svelte/store";

// We define a string to store the token data
let tokens = writable({
    refresh_token: "none",
    access_token: "none"
});
export  {tokens}
```

Basically I don't have any idea how can I keep the data stored inside the layout with my store

This is the output:

I must have always the same token data at any page or component...

[image]

Comment: Why are you returning the store inside braces?  This is creating an object with a single property (`tokens`), whose value is the writeable store.

Comment: Furthermore, I don't think you can send a store as data.  I might be wrong, though.  What you should do is just return the auth data as data.  Then, in the layout, you store this in a reactive store, ready to be used elsewhere.  Note, however, that visiting the page probably triggers re-authentication.  I don't think the server's `load()` function is the best place for authentication because you may be regenerating the tokens unecessarily.

Comment: Thats awesome, I will definitively try it out, thank you so much!

Can you help me by providing an example, about how to pass the auth data as data and how to store it in a reactive store?